# Why is WinAPI not creating the window with the configured size?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am fairly new to C++ coding so this could be a really easy fix. I have recently created a basic WinMain window. When I run the program from either the IDE or .exe file the application doesn't open at the proper size.

[image]

I can resize the window but I'm not sure why it isn't opening at that size set.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h> 

// Function prototypes
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);
bool CreateMainWindow(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
// global variable
HINSTANCE hinst;

// Constants 
const char CLASS_NAME[] = "WinMain";
const char APP_TITLE[] = "Hello World";
const char WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;  
const char WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;

//==================================
// Starting point for the windows application
// Parameters are
// hInstance. Handle to the current instance of the application 
// hPrevInstance. Always NULL, obsolete parameter
// lpCmdLine. Pointer to null-terminated string of command arguements 
// nCmdShow. Specifies how the window is to be shown 
//=================================
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE    hInstance,
    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR       lpCmdLine,
    int         nCmdShow )

{
    MSG msg;
    // Create thw window 
    if (!CreateMainWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow))
        return false;
    // Main message loop 
    int done = 0;
    while (!done)
    {
        // PeekMessage is a non blocking message for Windows messages 
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            // Look for quit message
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                done = 1;
            // Decode and pass messages on to WinProc
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

        }

    }
    return msg.wParam;

    }

// Window event callback function 
LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
            //Tell windows to kill this program 
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

}

// Create the window, returns False on error
bool CreateMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcx;
    HWND hwnd;

    // Fill in the window class structure with parameters 
    // That describe the main window 
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);               // Size of the structure 
    wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;    // Redraw if the size changes 
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;              // Points to windows procedure 
    wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;                     // No extra class memory 
    wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;                     // No extra window memory
    wcx.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcx.hIcon = NULL;
    wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);      // Predifined arrow
    // Background brush
    wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;    // Name of menu resource 
    wcx.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME; // Name of window class
    wcx.hIconSm = NULL;

    // Register the window class
    // RegisterClassEx return 0 on error
    if (RegisterClassEx(&wcx) == 0) // if error 
        return false;
    // Create Window
    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Name of window class
        APP_TITLE,                      // Title bar text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  // Default horizontal postion of window
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  // Default vertical postion of window
        WINDOW_WIDTH,                   // Width of window 
        WINDOW_HEIGHT,                  // Height of window 
        (HWND) NULL,                    // No parent window 
        (HMENU) NULL,                   // No menu
        hInstance,                      // Handle to application window
        (LPVOID) NULL);                 // No window parameters
    // If there was an error the window
    if (!hwnd)
        return false;
    // Show the window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    // Send a WM_PAINT message to the window procedure 
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the two constant definitions from `char` to `int`:

```
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;  
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
```

Assuming a signed character is 8-bits then `char x = 400` actually sets x to 16.

Comment: Nice one, +1 from me !

Comment: You have no idea how long I stared at that code! Thanks alot, I'm not sure why my programming book told me to do it that way.

Comment: @PapaSmurf Listen to your compiler **warnings**. They are helpful.